how to get instance of org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependency in custom plugin
My scenario is to apply other plug-ins in my customized plug-in, but before applying other plug-ins, the dependencies must be configured, otherwise an error will be reported when running, and the plug-in cannot be found, so I want to configure the plug-in dependencies when applying the plug-in. , this will automatically download the plug-in
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        //If you apply it directly like this, an error will be reported. The plug-in cannot be found. It must be configured first in plugins{} of build.gradle in the root directory.
        //Is there a way for me to configure the dependencies of the plugin here so that I don’t need to configure it in plugin{} of build.gradle?
        target.apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose")
    }
}

I tried to get the org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependency object in the Plugin so that I can add dependencies, but I didn't find how to get the PluginDependency object in the Plugin.

It shouldn't be necessary to "add dependencies" before applying a plugin. Perhaps some preparatory steps are necessary, but I wouldn't call them that. I suggest you share the code you would like to run to "add dependencies" if you could to help point you in the right direction

Add the plugin as dependency to the build script of the project that builds the plugin.
If you just want to apply it via ID, you can use runtimeOnly, if you also need to do some configuration and need classes of that plugin in your code like extensions added and so on, use implementation.
For the dependency, you can either look up the actual code artifact coordinates and depend on those (in the case of org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose this would be org.jetbrains.kotlin:compose-compiler-gradle-plugin:<version>), or you can use the marker artifact that otherwise is used to translate a plugin id from the plugins { ... } block to a dependency in normal build scripts, in your case this would be org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose:org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose.gradle.plugin:<version>. (generally it is <plugin id>:<plugin id>.gradle.plugin:<plugin version>)
